# regarding coding scheme in a thesis

Tags: thesis

I want to ask:
where should I give tables of interview codes in my PhD thesis? should I give themes in ch 4 and codes in appendix or codes should also be given in ch 4?

i am using embedded mixed method Qual+quant.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, questions about the content of research are outside of the scope of this site, so your question is very likely to be closed for being off topic.

Answer (score 1):

## Ask your advisor.

We don’t have the knowledge of your particular paper to be able to give in depth answer on how you should structure it. Your advisor, however, probably does, so you should probably ask them about it.

Comment: +1.  This is one of the (many) things an advisor is for.